# SQL - Create a new table by joining two tables based on Start and End values and then Concatenate rows based on Start and End values?

Tags: sql, join, concatenation, sql-server-2016, common-table-expression

This is a follow up question of [How to extract multiple rows from a table based on values from multiple columns from another table and then concatenate in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65837018/how-to-extract-multiple-rows-from-a-table-based-on-values-from-multiple-columns). I am new to SQL. I have 2 tables Table 1 and Table 2. Table 1 have columns ID, SSTART, SEND, UPSTART, UPEND, DNSTART, DNSTAND. Table 2 have columns Position and Seq.

Table 1

| ID | UPSTART | UPEND | SStart | SEnd | DNSTART | DNEND |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 98 | 99 | 100 | 104 | 105 | 106 |
| 2 | 98 | 99 | 100 | 104 | 105 | 106 |
| 3 | 100 | 101 | 102 | 106 | 107 | 108 |
| 4 | 100 | 101 | 102 | 106 | 107 | 108 |

Table 2

| Position | Seq |
| --- | --- |
| 98 | M |
| 99 | N |
| 100 | A |
| 101 | T |
| 102 | C |
| 103 | T |
| 104 | G |
| 105 | T |
| 106 | T |
| 107 | G |
| 108 | T |
| 109 | G |

My final table needs Columns ID, SStart, SSEnd, FullSeq,  UPStart, UPEnd, UPSeq, DNStart, DNStand, DnSeq as shown below:

| ID | UpStart | UpEnd | UpSeq | SStart | SSEnd | FullSeq | DNStart | DNStand | DnSeq |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 98 | 99 | MN | 100 | 104 | ATCTG | 105 | 106 | TT |
| 2 | 98 | 99 | MN | 100 | 104 | ATCTG | 105 | 106 | TT |
| 3 | 100 | 101 | AT | 102 | 106 | CTGTT | 107 | 108 | GT |
| 4 | 100 | 101 | AT | 102 | 106 | CTGTT | 107 | 108 | GT |

I am using SQL server 2016. I tried

```
; WITH SequenceCTE AS(
     SELECT  
     [ID] , 
     [SStart],
     [SSEnd],
     [UpStart],
     [UpEnd],
     Seq,
    [DnStart],
    [DnEnd],
    [Position]
  FROM Table_1 a
        JOIN Table_2 b
            ON b.Position >= a.[UpStart] AND
              b.Position <= a.[DnEnd]
)


SELECT  DISTINCT
    a.ID,
    a.[UpStart],
    a.[UpEnd],      
    UpSeq = (
        SELECT  STUFF(',' + Seq,1,1,'')
        FROM    SequenceCTE b
        WHERE   
                 a.ID = b.ID AND
                 a.[Position] > = b.[UpStart] AND
                 a.[Position] < = b.[UpEnd] AND
                 
                order by b.Position
        FOR XML PATH ('') 
        
        
    ) , 
    
    a.[SStart], 
    a.[SSEnd],
    FullSeq =  (
        SELECT  STUFF(',' + Seq,1,1,'')
        FROM    SequenceCTE b
        WHERE   
                 a.ID = b.ID AND
                 a.[SStart] = b.[SStart] AND
                 a.[SSEnd] = b.[SSEnd]
                order by b.Position
        FOR XML PATH ('') 
        
        
    ) , 
   
    a.[DnStart],
    a.[DnEnd],
    DownSeq = (
        SELECT  STUFF(',' + Seq,1,1,'')
        FROM    SequenceCTE b
        WHERE   
                 a.ID = b.ID AND
                a.[Position] > = b.[DnStart] AND
                a.[Position] < =  b.[DnEnd]                 
                order by b.Position
                
        FOR XML PATH ('') 
        
    )
FROM    SequenceCTE a
```

But it didn't work. Then  I tried

```
With FullSeqCTE as(
 Select * ,
 b1.Seq as FullSeq 
 from Table_1 a 
 join Table_2 b1 ON b1.Position >= a.SStart and b1.Position <= a.SSEnd
 ), UpperSeqCTE as(
 Select * ,
 b2.Seq as UpSeq
 from Table_1 a 
join Table_2 b2 ON b2.Position >= a.UpStart and b2.Position <= a.UpEnd
), LowerSeqCTE as (
Select * ,
b3.Seq as DownSeq
 from Table_1 a 
 join Table_2 b3 ON b3.Position > = a.DnStart and b3.Position < = a.DnEnd
)
```

But I am not sure how to proceed. Thank you very much for all the help.

**Create Statement Table 1**

```
   CREATE TABLE [Table_1](
    [SStart] [int] NULL,
    [SSend] [int] NULL,
    [ID] [int] NULL,
    [UpStart] [int] NULL,
    [UpEnd] [int] NULL,
    [DnStart] [int] NULL,
    [DnEnd] [int] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

**Insert Statement Table 1**

```
  INSERT INTO [Table_1]
       ([ID]        
       ,[UpStart]
       ,[UpEnd]
        ,[SStart]
         ,[SSend]
       ,[DnStart]
       ,[DnEnd])
   VALUES
       (1,98,99,100,104,105,106),
       (2,98,99,100,104,105,106),
       (3,100,101,102,106,107,108),
       (4,100,101,102,106,107,108)
 GO
```

**Create Statement Table 2**

```
 CREATE TABLE [Table_2](
  [Position] [int] NULL,
  [Seq] [nvarchar](1) NULL
 ) ON [PRIMARY]
Go
```

**Insert Statement for Table 2**

```
 INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table_2]
       ([Position]
       ,[Seq])
 VALUES
       (98,'M'),
       (99,'N'),
       (100,'A'),
       (101,'T'),
       (102,'C'),
       (103,'T'),
       (104,'G'),
       (105,'T'),
       (106,'T'),
       (107,'G'),
       (108,'T'),
       (109,'G')
GO
```

Comment: please also tag your DBMS

Comment: This sample data is too limited for a valid solution. There are multiple rows in `table_2` for  `Position=100`. Without an extra field to join on, the database engine will never be able to distinguish the rows. Also, changing your data type for `table_2.Seq` from `nchar(10)` to `nvarchar(1)` looks appropriate.

Comment: That was a mistake from my side. The entries in table 2 is unique and has only one Seq for each position. I made the changes in the question.

Comment: Can you just tag your DBMS as indicated by the first comment, please? For my solution I need to know if you are working on version 2017 or later...

Comment: Answer updated with SQL2016 version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using common table expressions (`cte_Up`, `cte_S`, `cte_Dn`) to limit the required groupings.

**Solution 1**

When working with SQL Server 2017 or later, you can use the `STRING_AGG()` function to concatenate columns.

```
with cte_Up as
(
  select t1.Id, string_agg(t2.Seq, '') within group (order by t2.Position) as UpSeq
  from table_1 t1
  join table_2 t2
    on  t2.Position >= t1.UpStart
    and t2.Position <= t1.UpEnd
  group by t1.Id
),
cte_S as
(
  select t1.Id, string_agg(t2.Seq, '') within group (order by t2.Position) as SSeq
  from table_1 t1
  join table_2 t2
    on  t2.Position >= t1.SStart
    and t2.Position <= t1.SEnd
  group by t1.Id
),
cte_Dn as
(
  select t1.Id, string_agg(t2.Seq, '') within group (order by t2.Position) as DnSeq
  from table_1 t1
  join table_2 t2
    on  t2.Position >= t1.DnStart
    and t2.Position <= t1.DnEnd
  group by t1.Id
)
select t1.Id,
       t1.UpStart,
       t1.UpEnd,
       u.UpSeq,
       t1.SStart,
       t1.SEnd,
       s.SSeq,
       t1.DnStart,
       t1.DnEnd,
       d.DnSeq
from table_1 t1
join cte_Up u
  on u.Id = t1.Id
join cte_S s
  on s.Id = t1.Id
join cte_Dn d
  on d.Id = t1.Id;
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=41c35cbc464841746c83eeb860eef965) to see things in action.

---

**Solution 2**

Using the `for xml` clause to achieve string concatenation when `string_agg()` is not availabe.

```
with cte_Up as
(
  select t1.Id,
         ( select '' + t2.Seq
           from table_2 t2
           where t2.Position >= t1.UpStart
             and t2.Position <= t1.UpEnd
           order by t2.Position
           for xml path('') ) as UpSeq
  from table_1 t1
),
cte_S as
(
  select t1.Id,
         ( select '' + t2.Seq
           from table_2 t2
           where t2.Position >= t1.SStart
             and t2.Position <= t1.SEnd
           order by t2.Position
           for xml path('') ) as SSeq
  from table_1 t1
),
cte_Dn as
(
  select t1.Id,
         ( select '' + t2.Seq
           from table_2 t2
           where t2.Position >= t1.DnStart
             and t2.Position <= t1.DnEnd
           order by t2.Position
           for xml path('') ) as DnSeq
  from table_1 t1
)
select t1.Id,
       t1.UpStart,
       t1.UpEnd,
       u.UpSeq,
       t1.SStart,
       t1.SEnd,
       s.SSeq,
       t1.DnStart,
       t1.DnEnd,
       d.DnSeq
from table_1 t1
join cte_Up u
  on u.Id = t1.Id
join cte_S s
  on s.Id = t1.Id
join cte_Dn d
  on d.Id = t1.Id;
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=3aed26a475a14a29d706e29914e56e6e) to see things in action.

---

**Result**

```
Id | UpStart UpEnd UpSeq | SStart SEnd SSeq  | DnStart DnEnd DnSeq
-- | ------- ----- ----- | ------ ---- ----- | ------- ----- -----
1  | 98       99   MN    | 100    104  ATCTG | 105     106   TT
2  | 98       99   MN    | 100    104  ATCTG | 105     106   TT
3  | 100      101  AT    | 102    106  CTGTT | 107     108   GT
4  | 100      101  AT    | 102    106  CTGTT | 107     108   GT
```